# Indexing numpy arrays with different number of dimensions

Tags: python, numpy

I am using numpy and I want to store the result of a calculation inside a three *or* four-dimensional matrix. I want to do something like this:

```
result[:, indices, iteration] = some_function()  # won't work
```

where the dimension is understood from the length of the `indices` tuple. So if `indices` equals, say, `(6,)` or `(8, 5)` then I want to have the equivalent of

```
result[:, 6, iteration] = some_function()
```

or

```
result[:, 8, 5, iteration] = some_function()
```

Normally I'd put all of the coordinates into a tuple and use that as an index, but the presence of `:` prevents me from doing that.

The dimension of `result` has been set earlier to the correct dimension, so can check it, but it would be nice to only use the length of `indices` to determine it. Is there some way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using `result[(slice(None),) + indices + (iteration,)]`

Answer (score 1):

If you need to know the length of indices :

```
len(indices)
```

But is it this your question ?

Comment: No, I know can check the length. And if it is 1 I could do result[:, indices[0], iteration] = ..., or if it is 2, result[:, indices[0], indices[1], iteration] = ... But I think it would be nicer if I can do something like the first line in my question rather than using an if statement to figure out the length.

Comment: There will always be an "if", even if you do not write it explicitly, I think.

Comment: That is okay, as long as I don't have to write it explicitly. That way I can easily add more dimensions later without adding more conditions to check for. (Even though I already know I won't add any more dimensions)